# Number of cpu cores change in my systrace output

Tags: cpu

I have 4 cores cpu on my device,
but each time I use this command line to genetrate a systrace file :

```
python C:/Users/BJI/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/systrace/systrace.py freq idle -o C:/Users/BJI/Desktop/systrace
```

I get a different number of cores (2 or sometimes 1 core cpu),
is it only the number of active cores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check how many `cpu<?>` under  `/sys/devices/system/cpu/`

for example, If CPU has two cores, there should be

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1
```

Comment: I have 4 cores, even in my power_profile.xml I get 4 cores cpu, but it is different for the systrace output, sometimes I get 2, other times I get 1 core ...

Comment: if there is no trace event happened on that core, the systrace won't show the cpu core.  there is a very common power saving strategy when you turn screen off, the system will unplug some cores to save power; BTW, Is there some IM groups we can chat with each others to share experience with android. for example, port android to a new arm device?

Comment: thank you for your help @kevin , I don't know if this helps but here [ https://community.arm.com/f ] is arm community  where you can find many forums